# xAxis event do not call the callback function

Tags: highcharts

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sssdajsL/2/)

Can someone explain, why the

```
     xAxis: { //...
         events: {
             pointBreak: function()...
         }
     }
```

does not work ?

See the JSFiddle example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug, so I reported this case to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4533

Comment: Thank you. I will follow the bugreport on github.